# How do I achieve this glow/blur highlight effect in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layer-style

[image]
I've been trying to mess around with radial blurs and glows for a few hours, but nothing looks quite as good as this.

Any insight would be much appreciated !

Comment: Maybe you can show what you've tried so we can identify where you are off?

Answer (score 1):

Start with your object set as white on a layer by itself against a black background layer.

[image]

Duplicate the shape, and on the duplicate run `Filter > Blur > Radial Blur` set to zoom.

[image]

Then place your duplicate (un-blurred) layer above the blur layer.

[image]

You can't accomplish this with the canned Layer Styles.

Comment: Yeah, I was using this blur method but it produces a very even blur around the image and not the lens flare type of effect I was looking for. 

Thanks for the reply though!

Comment: I think I'm just going to have to do it manually

Comment: You can blur, then mask the blur. You can also use multiple blur layers.